# jQuery- How to update URL on select change

Tags: jquery

I am building a "build your own" type of functionality onto my site where a user can select options for a particular item and the image and price is updated accordingly.

Each option will be in the form of a select box.

I would like to make it so that as each option is changed, the URL is updated so the user can save the link and revisit it later. Notice how this website does it:

http://www.gemvara.com/jewelry/fiona-marquise-ring/marquise-aquamarine-14k-white-gold-ring/1n4zg

Each time you change an option, the URL is updated, but the page is not refreshed. How is that done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably read this tutorial:
http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/history.html

It explains exactly what you are trying to do, and it even include some examples.